# Create a new variable using IF, THEN, & Random value creation

Tags: r

I am trying to write R code that

1. creates a new variable
2. populates that variable only if METRO=0
3. the values that are populated are a random assignment of "1" and "2" values.

I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
iPUMS_2016 <- mutate (iPUMS_2016, metrounk = ifelse(METRO==0,mutate(rand_int=sample.int(n())) ))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't need the second `mutate` inside the `ifelse`.  Also, it could be a `if/else` condition i.e. `if` all the elements in 'METRO' are 0 then get the `sample.int` on the number of rows

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(iPUMS_2016, metrounk = if(all(METRO == 0)) sample.int(n()) else  METRO)
```

---

If it is to replace only elements that are 0.

```
mutate(iPUMS_2016, metrounk = ifelse(METRO == 0, sample.int(n()), METRO))
```

The `sample.int(n())` is not clear.  Or it should be `sample.int(sum(METRO == 0))`

```
mutate(iPUMS_2016, metrounk = replace(METRO, METRO == 0, 
               sample.int(sum(METRO == 0, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Wondering what I would need to use with or instead of sample.int(n()) in order to get randomly assigned "1" and "2" values to the new variable "metrounk"

Comment: @Quantitative72  I guess you need `sample(c("1", "2", n(), replace = TRUE)`

Comment: I tried this 'iPUMS_2016 <- mutate(iPUMS_2016, metrounk = ifelse(METRO == 0, sample(c("5", "6", n(), replace = TRUE), METRO)))' but got this Error in ifelse(METRO == 0, sample(c("5", "6", n(), replace = TRUE), METRO)) : argument "no" is missing, with no default

Comment: @Quantitative72  I think it is a mistake on your part `sample(c("5", "6", n()` The `c()` bracket is not closed

Comment: Thanks for identifying the bracket issue. After running my freq look like that below. Any idea why it is giving me "3156487" as a metrounk value and not "6"?
<chr>
n
<int>
1 327920   
2 307598   
3 776585   
3156487 169633   
4 1235818   
5 338933

Comment: @Quantitative72  Can you use `dput` to sshow the example as I can't get the exact structure

Comment: Not sure how to use dput. Are you looking for the output table or the full dataset?

Comment: @Quantitative72  I just need 10 - 15 rows i.e. `dput(head(droplevels(iris)))`  iris is inbuilt example, change that to your dataest.  Just run it on your console and copy/paste the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207133/discussion-between-quantitative72-and-akrun).